# Large archive table with "unimportant" data, how to improve/redesign?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance

We have a SQL DB that collects analog and digital sensor data from several hundred devices. The archive table is quite simple, just a (datetime) timestamp, (int) stationId, (int) datatapointId and (double) value (plus 3 bool flags).

The DB collects about 12 million entries per month. This table is supposed to be always growing, no rollbacks, updates or deletions are neccessary.

The main purpose of this table is to be used to show archive values in our web visualization ordered by timestamp and filtered by this or that id, therefore I created the relevant indexes for the fields I need. It works, but the performance is quite poor (about 5 seconds when filtering by a start/end time, stationId and datapointId).

What would be a better way to store and query this kind of data? Is SQL Server Standard 2016 perhaps not the right DBMS for such an archive? The original decision to use SQL Server dates back several years when the amount of data was way smaller than today. Is there some magic in SQL Server that I can apply to trade reliability for performance?

Comment: Hi there, could you add examples of the indexes and the kind of queries you are using? Adding the query plan to [pastetheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) could also help in getting a correct answer faster.

Comment: Also, the table creation DDL would be good to have!

Comment: I know the question relates to SQL server, but under mysql/mariadb there are different database engine types that have different characteristics and may help one solution over another.  Are there any different 'engines' under SQL server you could investigate?

Comment: if you are querying for timestamp, datapointID and stationId, an index like this could work: `CREATE INDEX IX_stationId_datapointId_timestamp
ON dbo.archive(stationId,datapointId,timestamp)
INCLUDE(INSERTCOLUMNSINSELECTCLAUSEHERE)` . Just add the selected columns in the INCLUDE clause.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I intentionally did not post my code as I am mainly interested in how *your* approach would be given the handful of fields mentioned in my question, with pure performance and no or little reliability in mind. @Randi: you're right, an index is a huge step forward (already have one), but I'm curious to see some not-so-obvious tricks and tweaks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which database could handle storage of billions/trillions of records?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38793/which-database-could-handle-storage-of-billions-trillions-of-records)

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know where that 5 seconds goes. Is it disk, network, memory or CPU?

Guessing it's disk there are ways to speed this up. One is to get faster disk: flash or NVMe would be nice! Another, more plausible solution, is to compress the data so less IO is required for the same information content. SQL Server supports [several options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression). Also look into [clustered columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview). These are specifically designed to efficiently store and process large amounts of data.

Looking outside SQL Server it sounds like you have time-series data. There are [many DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database) specifically tailored to this use-case.

Before you go that far you may look into refactoring your application architecture. Since the data is write-once you can pre-process, or at least cache, any query against it. What visualisations do you use? Often data is aggregated so, say, min, max and average per hour/ day/ minute are shown. If this is your case you can pre-calculate these aggregates, store them and remove the detailed data. If you use n-tiles, candlesticks or line charts, calculate the corresponding SVG, PNG or JPEG once for each interval, and stitch them together to make larger charts. A lot of this store-and-stitch can be done in the file system or CDN avoiding load on the DB server at all.

Comment: Thanks Michael. There are some interesting points you make here and I already tried some of them, namely pre-aggregating to fixed time slices of 15min, 1h and so on. I also have a stored procedure that can produce custom-sized slices on the fly based on the number of pixels available in my DIY chart built with d3.js (you don't need more data than you can actually perceive). I'm mainly interested in tweaking SQL SERVER settings, using a different DB engine, setting some little known parameters, things like that. And yes, a DBMS aimed at time series is definitely worth a look.